# When does sshpass close a connection

Tags: server, ssh, remote, sshpass

I am using sshpass in a script which executes rsync and backup a file from remote server, I added that script to cron which runs every minute. Now I am concerned about the connections, does the connection remains opened? how shall I close the connection when rsync is done?

Is this handled by sshpass internally, please suggest some alternative if connections are left open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sshpass` is only wrapper to provide password to the `rsync`/`ssh` command inside. Once the `rsync` ends, the connection is automatically closed.